Regex for obtaining product IDs
I'm having a problem with getting this regex to only match the items product IDs that start with a 1. So far this is the pattern I come up with.
def find_productID(report):
  pattern = r'\d{4}-[A-Z][A-Z]-\d{2}' #enter the regex pattern here
  result = re.findall(pattern, report) #enter the re method  here
  return result



print(find_productID("Products 1234-AB-30 and 2234-AB-30, not items 12-AB-30 or 12345-AB-30")) # Should return ['1234-AB-30']
print(find_productID("Products of interest are 1234-AB-30, 1678-XZ-11, and 1561-CD-57. We're not interested in other products like 2345-AB-29.")) # Should return ['1234-AB-30', '1678-XZ-11', '1561-CD-57']

r'\d{4}-[A-Z][A-Z]-\d{2}'.

You can replace the \d{4} at the beginning of the regex by 1\d{3}

Just in case you want to avoid matches in longer strings, use word boundaries, too: r'\b1\d{3}-[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}\b'

@MichaelButscher, that would match "1234-AB-30" in "Products 91234-AB-30". You need to either do what Wiktor suggests or use a negative lookbehind: r'(?<!\d)1\d{3}-[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}\b', the choice depending on requirements. Similarly, you could use a word boundary or negative lookahead at the end.

Use this pattern instead to consider first digit as 1:
r'1\d{3}-[A-Z][A-Z]-\d{2}'


Winner winner chicken dinner, thank you!
